# Couldnt start {0} EAP due to a login problem. Please contact technical support for assistance

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains

Не удается войти в аккаунт JetBrains(RubyMine). Такая же проблема и в IntelliJ IDEA
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот поэтому я не пользуюсь редакторами, которые требуют интернета для работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-279055. На вашем компьютере настроен прокси-сервер? Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующие рекомендации: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407356204178-IDE-Can-t-Connect-to-JetBrains-Account-to-Start-a-Trial . .

Comment: Cо второй ссылки все перепробывал  и ничего. А прокси не понимаю, как они настраивали

Comment: Проблема так и не решилась. Буду искать другую среду разробки, больше нет сил на это.